# Build a simple PHP proxy server for a shared host

Tags: php, proxy, telegram, http-proxy, socks

I've searched a lot but I couldn't find a PHP proxy server which can be run on a shared host, so I decided to build a very simple one from scratch but I'm still on the first step. I've created a subdomain `httpp.alvandsoft.com` and also redirected all its subdirectories (`REQUEST_URI`) to the main `index.php` to be logged and to know what whould a proxy server exactly receive and send

(The log is accessible through https://httpp.alvandsoft.com/?log=1&log_filename=log.txt)

But whenever I set it as a proxy for Telegram or other apps, it doesn't receive ANY requests at all, even when I use 443 or 80 ports, neither in different proxies such as `HTTP`, `SOCKS` or `MTPROTO`.

Is proxy something that depends on the server's settings and works in a way other than regular `HTTP` requests and responses or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I found it out myself. `HTTP(s)` proxies send their requested URL as `Host` request header and many hosts and websites, check this request header and if it's not a member of their valid IPs, redirect it immediately.